# Mathematical soundness of arguing like this for this limit calculation?

Tags: analysis, limits

I wanted to calculate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n + 2^n)^{1\over n}$$
and my result is correct but I don't know if my argument is mathematically acceptable. I argued as follows:

For large $n$ we have $n + 2^n$ more or less equal to $2^n$.

From there it was easy to calculate the limit.

But even though it's clear to me that the argument is correct I wonder if it's rigorous. I suspect not.

> (1) Is there a mathematically rigorous way to do exactly this argument?
>
> (2) And if not, what is the simplest way of calculating this limit?

Comment: you usually compute limits of sequences by finding two other easier sequences, one lower and one higher then yours, that converge to the same limit. 
You found the lower bound, but you need an upper bound

Comment: "For large n we have n+2^n more or less equal to 2^n".  That's true.  But it's also true "you can just tell by looking at it that the answer is 2".  You must give a reason *why* for large n you have n+2^n is more or less equal to 2^n.

Answer (score 2):

The following should be a "rigorous" way.

We have that for $n\geq 1$, $n\leq 2^n$ and
$$2\leq (n + 2^n)^{1\over n}=2\left(1+\frac{n}{2^n}\right)^{1\over n}\leq2\cdot 2^{1\over n}$$
and by the [Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem), 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{1\over n}=1\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} (n + 2^n)^{1\over n}=1.$$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Observe the algebraic trick:

$$\left(n+2^n\right)^{1/n}=2\left(1+\frac n{2^n}\right)^{1/n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2\cdot 1=2$$

because (well, the rightmost limit is standard, but if you need explanation...)

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac n{2^n}\right)=1\implies \text{ exists}\;N\in\Bbb N\;s.t.\;\;n>N\implies\frac12<1+\frac n{2^n}<\frac32\implies $$

and now use the squeeze theorem:

$$1\xleftarrow[\infty\leftarrow x]{}\sqrt[n]\frac12<\sqrt[n]{1+\frac n{2^n}}<\sqrt[n]\frac32\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are familiar with L'Hospital's rule for finding the limit.

Let $L=(n+2^n)^\frac{1}{n}$.Then $$\ln L = \frac{\ln(n+2^n)}{n}$$

As $n\to\infty$, $\ln(n+2^n)\to \infty$ and we get an indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.So, we can apply L'Hospital's rule here.

So, we get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(n+2^n)}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1+2^n \ln 2}{n+2^n} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n(\ln 2)^2}{1+2^n \ln 2} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^n(\ln 2)^3}{2^n(\ln 2)^2} = \ln 2. $$

Since logarithm is continuous function, we conclude that $$\ln(\lim_{n\to\infty}L) = \ln2 $$  , i.e., $$\lim_{n\to\infty}L = 2. $$

Answer (score 0):

You need only note that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(n+2^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} &=2\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{n}{2^n}\right)^{\frac{2^n}{n}\frac{1}{2^n}}\\
&= 2\,e^0 = 2.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

First
$$e^{\ln{(n+2^{n})^{1/n}}} = (n+2^{n})^{1/n}$$
so
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n + 2^n)^{1\over n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\ln{(n+2^{n})^{1/n}}}$$
we know
$$\ln{(n+2^{n})^{1/n}} = \frac{1}{n}\ln{(n+2^n)}\\
\ln{(2^{n}) = n\ln(2)}\\
e^{\ln(x)} = x,\ x>0$$
for Big values of $n$, when $n$ is infinite ($n \to \infty$), we have 
$$2^n\gg n \Rightarrow n+2^n \simeq 2^n$$
so
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} (n + 2^n)^{1\over n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\ln{(n+2^{n})^{1/n}}}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln{(n+2^{n})}}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}\ln{(2^{n})}}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\frac{n}{n}\ln{(2)}}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\ln{(2)}}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} e^{\ln{(2)}}\\
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} 2 \\
&= 2
\end{align}
$$